# CakePHP 2.4 - how to save copy of data in other model before edit?

Tags: cakephp, copy, edit, archive

I've got 2 simple models:

**Entry**

- id
- title
- content
- user_id
- category_id

and

**Archive**

- id
- title
- content
- reason
- user_id
- category_id
- entry_id

I would like to ask how can I **save copy** of Entry as Archive **before editing** it and add reason of editing? I would like to do it as the most correct way in CakePHP.

This will be the only way to add data to Archive model (editing Entry).

Should I just include Archive model in Entry, in edit function just create() Archive, copy data from Entry, manualy add reason from editing form and save() when edit will be done?

I need this functionality only when editing. Other actions will be standard.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your attempted solution and tell us what didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Modify your request data like so:

```
$this->request->data['Archive'] = $this->request->data['Entry']
$this->request->data['Archive']['entry_id'] = $this->request->data['Entry']['id']
unset($this->request->data['Archive']['id']); // don't need this for archives
```

This way the request has both the archive and entry data in it. You could include in your entry edit form the reason for editing. Since no field in entry has a reason.. it would not be saved. Also look into using the [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) method and it will take care of both save/update at the same time. This code is untested but would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

Sixthpoint - thanks. Your answer really helps me.

I made some changes in my code and here is part of my admin_edit function in EntriesController:

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

        //Load archive model and create object
        $this->loadModel('Archive');
        $this->Archive->create();

        //Geting data of current entry (yes, i want to save old, non-edited entry data in archives)
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Entry.' . $this->Entry->primaryKey => $id));
        $current_entry = $this->Entry->find('first', $options);

        //assignment to request data of archive
        $this->request->data['Archive'] = $current_entry['Entry'];

        //adding id for foregin key
        $this->request->data['Archive']['entry_id'] = $this->request->data['Entry']['id'];
        //adding reason from form data
        $this->request->data['Archive']['reason'] = $this->request->data['Entry']['reason'];
        //remove id, new entry of archive will be added
        unset($this->request->data['Archive']['id']);

        // save archive
        if ($this->Archive->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The archive has been saved.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The archive could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

        // save edited entry
        if ($this->Entry->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The entry has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The entry could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

Now I've got what I need. I'm getting old (before editted) Entry data and save it as Archive with reason.